# Devise registration and sign_in scoped by subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, scope, subdomain

My website can be duplicated on the fly by changing the (sub)domain. I have a Domain model and most of my other models (like User) `belongs_to :domain`. I don't want a SSO: each subdomain has its own users.

The two steps are :

- in registration create, before save, set domain_id to Domain.find_by_name(request.host)
- in session create, sign in with email, password and domain_id

But I do not find the right way to do any of this step...

Thank you very much for any help and sorry for my english!

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as 'Multitenancy' in web apps.  May help in your research.

Comment: https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant works like a charm, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a howto on this in the devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Isolate-users-to-log-into-a-single-subdomain

You would also need to handle saving that info when you create a user, which you could do easily in your users controller (or wherever you save user accounts when they sign up).

Comment: It seems fine but I finally use acts_as_tenant which works like a charm (I guess this gem uses this trick). Thank you!

Comment: I don't understdand how the warden conditions get passed the subdomain id. Could you help with that?